# Date loop with String

Tags: java, android, date, loops, calendar

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  //getting calendar

TextView  date, diet;
Button forward, back;
int count = 0;

String [] word;

@Override
protected void onCreate...

c.setFirstDayOfWeek(c.getFirstDayOfWeek()); //set first day (current day)

                    //mT is method from database, "1" is for Monday, "1" for diet;
final String[] word = { "" + mT(1, 1), "" + mT(1, 2), "" + mT(1, 3), 
"" + mT(1, 4), "" + mT(1, 5), "" + mT(1, 6), "" + mT(1, 7) };

 ....//...

SharedPreferences getPref = PreferenceManager
.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

final String values = getPref.getString("list", "4");
        if (values.contentEquals("1")) {

//this display String and corresponding day (example "2, Tuesday")
        diet.setText(word[c.getFirstDayOfWeek()]); 

        }

//on Click forward button 
forward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);                
            counter();


        if (values.contentEquals("1")) {
            diet.setText(word[c.getFirstDayOfWeek()+count]); }
```

String word is related to number of day and on click method it paralel shifts with day in a week 
(if day in a week is "Monday" it calls String "0" --> mT(1,1)

```
private void counter() {  //And this is simple loop

count++;
if(count>=7){ // --> 7 is number of days in a week
count=0;       // start from beginning
}
```

My problem is when String comes to 7 (last one -->...  mT(1, 7)) application crashes. 
But it needs to start from beginning (first String[] -->  mT(1,1)) and parallel with that to follow coresponding day in a week.

Can anyone help me with fixing this problem?

Comment: Post `mT` if that's where it's crashing. Also, let's see the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error needs some explanations. So, the first is, it has something to do with Your method:

```
   if (values.contentEquals("1")) {
        diet.setText(word[c.getFirstDayOfWeek()+count]); }
```

It must not be exactly this line, it can be every line where You are using a similar coding. Your error is caused by this:

```
   word[c.getFirstDayOfWeek()+count]
```

So if You are calling `c.getFirstDayOfWeek()` , it will give You a minimum value of 1 (1 for sunday, 2 for monday....and so on). Calendar days are counted from 1 on, but Arrays are starting to count by 0. If You are calling this method `word[c.getFirstDayOfWeek()+count])`, You will get a minimum like this `word[1]);`. 
First problem is, You will never reach `word[0]`, second problem is, You will get an ArrayOutOfBoundException because the highest value You will get (because of Your counter) is 7 (counters highest value is 6 + minmimum firstDayOfWeek 1). But Arrays starting by 0, the highest possible value You can reach with Your array is 6 (word[6]).

### Solution

I don´t know why You are using this `word[c.getFirstDayOfWeek()+count]` like this way, but from the code I can see, You only need to call `word[count]`.

For more help, You should post the stacktrace and the full code.